How to implement a UserControl with functionalities of a ListView, a Canvas instead of a list, and shapes like lines as item's view?
This is not a duplicate of Bind collection of lines to canvas in WPF
since I need to use an ObservableCollection of ViewModels and all other functionalities of ListView (selections, SelectedItem binding etc), and I am not binding just lines but something arbitrary (another UserControl, lines, rect, text etc), and positionned on Canvas.
ItemsControl does not provide selection functionalities.
The goal is to have a UserControl, says CanvasView with multiple lines, positioned thanks to a Canvas, with the similar functionalities of a ListView (selecteditem(s), add/remove, etc), and have it pluggable to an ObservableCollection.
I have an ObservableCollection of items (VideoMarker):
public class VideoMarker
{
    public int ID { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get;}

    public VideoMarker(int position, int id, string name)
    {
        Created = DateTime.Now;
        Position = position;
        ID = id;
        Name = $"{name} {id}";
    }
}

in the ViewModel, says MarkersViewModel, associated to CanvasView:
public class MarkersViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<VideoMarker> Markers { get; } = new();
    // etc...
}

In the View, I will have something like this (for the principle):
    <Canvas>
        <Line SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" Y1="0"
              Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=videoRectInner}" X1="10" X2="10"/>
    </Canvas>

Except that I do not want to hardcode Line elements with those details, I need to have an ItemTemplate like
<CanvasView Name="vc0">
    <CanvasView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VideoMarker}">
            <Grid>
                <Line SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" Y1="0"
              Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=vc0}" X1="{Binding Position}" X2="{Binding Position}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CanvasView.ItemTemplate>
</CanvasView>

One of the benefits is to have the lines added or removed as ObservableCollection<VideoMarker> Markers have new or removed items, and have each with binding to whatever template I specify.
The dependency properties I am looking to use are ItemsSource, SelectedItem etc.
One other point, is how can I have CanvasView subclass Selector and UserControl ? I know I can subclass only one of them, so which should I use, and how should I implement the rest ?
How to implement CanvasView so I can use it and specify its ItemTemplate wherever I use it, an plug it (and its items) to an ObservableCollection ?
The best I could do so far is using ItemsControl, but I do not have selection features a ListView as:
<ItemsControl Name="canvasItemsInner"
              Canvas.Left="{Binding Position, Mode=OneTime}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Markers}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Line SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stroke="{Binding ID, Converter={StaticResource IDColorConverter}}"
                  Canvas.Left="{Binding Position}"
                  StrokeThickness="2" Y1="0"
                      Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=videoRectInner}"
                      X1="{Binding Position}" X2="{Binding Position}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>


Create the user controls on-the-fly and load them into whatever. Building a template to accomplish the same result is just using a more complicated, abstract way to arrive at the same place.

Are you not aware that a ListBox is an ItemsControl and that the solution in the duplicate question applies as well to a ListBox? That said, where is your own effort? What did you try?

@Clemens I do not want a listbox, but a Canvas instead, the closest, ItemsControl lacks selection features.

"ItemsControl lacks selection" - sure. That's why you would use a ListBox - with a Canvas as ItemsPanel as shown in the other post.

You may then even override the GetContainerForItemOverride method to create specialized item containers, instead of ListBoxItem.

@Clemens I could not use a ListBox instead of an ItemsControl. GetContainerForItemOverride  seems promising. Your comments seem to be more appropriate as an answer.
